# Backbone.js only creating first model, then returning the rest as undefined when parsing with Google Calendar

Tags: backbone.js, google-calendar-api

Having some issues with pulling calendar events from Google Calendar using Backbone.

When I call `collection.fetch()` I am only getting a length of 1 returned, when there are 13 objects in the json.

I had a look at the `parse:function(response)` method that I am overriding in the Collection, and it is returning all 13 objects. I had a look at the add method in backbone.js, and the issue appears to occur on line 591:

```
models = _.isArray(models) ? models.slice() : [models];
```

When I wrap the line with console.log to check the status of the models variable:

```
console.log(models);
models = _.isArray(models) ? models.slice() : [models];
console.log(models);
```

I get the following result:

```
[Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object] backbone.js:590
[child,undefined × 12]
```

I'm at a loss to explain why it would be failing on add. I have checked each model by changing the `parse:function(response)` method in the collection to return each object, and it works fine.:

```
parse: function(response) {
  return response.feed.entry[5];
}
```

I have successfully parsed Google Calendar feeds with Backbone.js before, so I fear I am missing something really simple.

If I `console.log` `response.feed` the following is returned:

[image: Screenshot of console dump]

This is the full class:

```
/**
* Backbone
* @class
*/

var Gigs = Gigs || {};

Gigs.Backbone = {}

Gigs.Backbone.Model = Backbone.Model.extend();

Gigs.Backbone.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Gigs.Backbone.Model,
  url: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/email@email.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&orderby=starttime&callback=?',
  sync: function(method, model, options) {
    options.dataType = "jsonp";
    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
  },
  parse: function(response) {
    return response.feed.entry;
  }
});

Gigs.Backbone.Controller = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.collection = new Gigs.Backbone.Collection();
    this.collection.on('reset', this.addElements, this);

    this.collection.fetch();
  },

  addElements: function() {
    log(this.collection);
  }

});

var backbone = new Gigs.Backbone.Controller();
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the models manually without using fetch (`collection.add(models)`)?

Comment: If I change `this.collection.fetch()` to:

`this.collection.add([
  { name: 'lol' },
  { name: 'lol' },
  { name: 'lol' },
  { name: 'lol' }
]);`

Then it works correctly. Or did you mean load them in and add them in a different way?

Comment: doesn't .slice() without any parameters simply return the original array? What result are you intending by calling models.slice()?

Comment: The `models = _.isArray(models) ? models.slice() : [models];` line is a part of the Backbone.js collection add method. `.add()` checks whether the models argument is an array; if it's not, it wraps it in one.

Comment: @superhighfives I meant load the same results separately and then add them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, Google Calendar provides its entries with an id wrapped in an object <sup>1</sup>:

```
"id":{
    "$t":"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/..."
}
```

which Backbone seems to dislike. A lot.

One simple solution would be to overwrite the id in your parse method:

```
parse: function(response) {
    var entries=[];

    _.each(response.feed.entry, function(entry,ix) {
        entry.id=entry.id.$t;
        entries.push(entry);
    });

    return entries;
}
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bqzkT/

<sup>1</sup> Check https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json to see how Google converts its XML data to JSON.

---

**Edit** : the problem comes from the way the data is returned with a straight XML to JSON conversion (requested via the `alt=json-in-script` parameter) wrapping the attributes in objects. Changing this parameter to `alt=jsonc` yields a much simpler JSON representation. Compare a [jsonc output](http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=jsonc&orderby=starttime) to the [json-in-script equivalent](http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&orderby=starttime).

See https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc#Comparing_JSON_and_JSONC for more info

Comment: This has worked! Thanks for the link, too, and the detailed explanation. You are a champion!

Comment: @superhighfives Found another representation of the data you might want to check.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help. Found it much cleaner to just work with `jsonc`, rather than `json-in-script`. Brilliant.